# Facial muscles and tightening the skin

Tags: neck

> Muscles like your biceps or your quadriceps, the muscles we are used
>   to working out are called skeletal muscles and their contractions and
>   extensions help control our bones. The muscles on our face however,
>   are attached from the bone underneath directly to the skin. This is
>   why and how we can make facial expressions. This is a good thing for
>   our plight because it means that with developing those muscles also
>   comes the potential for tightening the skin around them

Source: http://physicalblue.com/how-to-get-a-chiseled-jawline/

Is that statement correct ?

Does that mean that by doing facial exercise I can tighten the skin around the jaw, given that I don't have fat there and the skin is elastic ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_toning

Comment: re: close vote. I get that this on the fringe, but it's about muscles, strength, and "training". Would it have been on-topic if he has asked about how to make his glutes stronger and firmer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You may not be able to achieve perfect smoothness, but you can tighten things up over time.

Begin by stretching your jaw for about ten minutes every morning, opening and shutting, moving side to side. This must be done slowly as to avoid stress on the temporomandibular joint- if you feel a crackling sensation, you are going too wide. You can get your lips and eyebrows involved too. Imitate the [oh face guy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=3B-wVM34Ac3XoATN44HIBw&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DQzIN3EgBIHg&ved=0CB0Q3ywwAA&usg=AFQjCNF0l2XdQkcLnuUDxCOtQ3PvUgrHaw&sig2=kHvgP_2V_YCiYOPQsUHnnA) from office space, then furrow your brow and widen your mouth like [GW](http://dotdash.blogspot.com/bush2.jpg). Relecting this for a few minutes will get your facial muscials feeling more relaxed, which both prepares them to be exercised, and discourages the stress induced tension which pulls your skin in undesired ways.

Afterwards, exercise throughout the day be chewing gum. Try to do so while sitting, standing, and laying down at some time through the day. It's best if you can do so while leaning your head back and looking at the ceiling for a while, to help tone your digastrics. If you don't have gum, you can achieve similar affects by alternately pressing and releasing your tongue firmly against your palate.

Finally, before you go to bed, take about 60 seconds to smile hard, while rolling your head around in a circle to stretch your neck. (This is actually good practice regardless of your fitness goals, since sleeping with a pillow can be stressful to one's neck over time.)

Keeping up with this daily should yield noticeable results after about 90 days. This is a pretty long time, but training facial muscles is inherently slow. Luckily the exercises aren't hard to keep up with in and of themselves.

Good luck getting a buff face. It's worth it!

Comment: Where did you learn this?